# I won't able to pass the parameter to the .net web service in android

Tags: android, .net, web-services

When I am going to pass the parameters to the .NET web service I came to know the parameter is not getting the value. I put my code in the following link with my web service

```
//web service
<WebMethod()> _
    Public Function Hello(ByVal strText As String) As String
        Return "Hello " + strText
    End Function

//Android Code
package com.tt;

public class TrialconActivity extends Activity {

private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/Hello";
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "Hello";
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org";   
private static final String URL ="http://192.168.75.8/Web%20Service/Service1.asmx";

public TrialconActivity(){}

Object result = null;   
EditText ed1;
TextView password,tv1,tv2;
Button click; 

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    ed1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.eduser);
    click = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    click.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try{    
                SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

                password = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.edpass);

                String data = password.getText().toString();
                System.out.println("The String is :"+data);

                request.addProperty("strText", data);

                SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

                envelope.dotNet = true;

                envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

                AndroidHttpTransport aht=new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);

                aht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);   

                result =  envelope.getResponse();

                String ans = result.toString();

                ed1.setText(ans);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
             tv1.setText(e.toString());
        }
    }
        }); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is my code.  pastebin.com/jpmrKyyR

Comment: Please post the code. The link is not accessible.

Comment: I have posted my code here. So plz help me ...

Comment: Or u cn just copy paste this link on your new tab.

Comment: Use `HttpTransportSE` method instead of `AndroidHttpTransport`.

Comment: I solve my problem. The problem is NAMESPACE must end with "/".